# Authentication for Spark standalone cluster

Tags: security, hadoop, authentication, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a standalone Spark cluster running on a remote server and I'm new to Spark. It appears that there's no **authentication scheme** protecting the **cluster master's (7077) port** by default. Anyone can just simply submit their own code to the cluster without any restrictions.

The [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/security.html) states that authentication is possible in stand-alone deploy mode using the `spark.authenticate.secret` parameter, but doesn't really elaborate how exactly this should be used.

Is it possible to use some sort of **shared secret** that would prevent any potential attacker from submitting tasks to the cluster? Can anyone explain how exactly that can be configured?

Comment: One possibility is to use Kerberos, and you would require a Kerberos ticket to submit a job

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for your response. wouldn't that require a YARN deployment instead of a stand-alone Spark deployment?

Comment: Kerberos isn't tied to YARN, so not that I'm aware of. Though, you already tagged the question with Hadoop, so that would imply YARN is available. Some Cloudera documentation about Spark security - https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/sg_spark_auth.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there are 2 parts to enable support of authentication:

1. setting the secret on the master an all the slaves
2. using the same secret when submitting jobs to the cluster

## master and slaves

on each server in your cluster, add the following config to `conf/spark-defaults.conf`:

```
spark.authenticate.secret      SomeSecretKey
```

## submitting jobs

when you initialize the spark context, you should add the same config to it as well, ie:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
      .set("spark.authenticate.secret", "SomeSecretKey")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

or if you are using SparkSession:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .conf("spark.authenticate.secret", "SomeSecretKey")
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I ran into similar issue.  The standalone master and workers work fine with the secret in the spark-defaults.conf file.  However, when I try to use the --property-file option with the submit, I get an error the secret must be set.  I tried passing it as ENV variable, using the -conf option, and within the property file.  Would you know how to pass it from the spark-submit command line?

Comment: source shows:

.orElse(Option(secretKey)) .orElse(Option(sparkConf.getenv(ENV_AUTH_SECRET)))
.orElse(sparkConf.getOption(SPARK_AUTH_SECRET_CONF))


What is the correct way to add those to the submit command ?

Comment: If not using YARN, two are the parameters to set "spark.authenticate  true"  AND "spark.authenticate.secret      SomeSecretKey"